# Как объединить 2 таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Когда я отправляю товар, категория показывается а тип товара нет.Подскажите пожалуйста как объединить 2 таблицы(table_products и category) 2 столбцa таблицы type_tovara и type, чтобы они соответствовали brand и category. Вроде ясно написал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через union `select category, type_tovara from table_products union select brand, type from category`

Comment: @nick_n_a А мне показалось что join. хотя конечно непонятно написано. Вот сижу ищу наиболее подходящий ответ с джоином что бы по дублю закрыть. каждый день ведь спрашивают, а набрать в поиске тут "[mysql] две таблицы" и просто посмотреть примеры видать сложно ...

Comment: join присоиденяет столбцы таблицы обычно по-ключевому полю. А union обьединяет/слияет две таблицы. Поэтому смотря что вы называете "обьеденить"